# Jest setSystemTime not working with global scope

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am trying to tests a simple reducer which has a date property set to today.

```
const today = new Date();

export const initialState = {
  today
};

console.log(new Date().toDateString()); // <--- real date

export default function globalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(new Date().toDateString()); // <--- mocked date
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

with my basic test

```
import globalReducer from "./reducer";

describe("Global reducer", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers("modern");
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date("2021-02-18"));
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it("should return the mocked date", () => {
    expect(globalReducer(undefined, {}).today).toEqual(new Date('2021-02-18'));
  });
});
```

What I noticed is that the mock only works inside the reducer code, but today in its global scope always returns the real date instead of the mocked one.

If I call the `setSystemTime` in the test setup file, then `today` is correctly mocked.

Am I missing something here? What would be the way of mocking a date in global scope only for a specific test?

A test repo is here if you want to check it out https://github.com/dariospadoni/jestFakeTimersMock

Comment: That would be because the Date is instantiated in `recucer.js` before `setSystemTime` is invoked.

Comment: Yes, but does it mean that there is no way of mocking the date for this case? Unless using the setup files but that would have an impact on all the tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for it to happen is because the `Date` is instantiated in `recucer.js` before `setSystemTime` is invoked.

Here is an example how you can avoid that:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  jest.setSystemTime(new Date("2021-02-18"));
});

describe("Global reducer", () => {
  let globalReducer;

  beforeAll(() => {
    globalReducer = require("./reducer").default;
  });

  it("should return the mocked date", () => {
    expect(globalReducer(undefined, {}).today).toEqual(new Date("2021-02-18"));
  });
});
```

Here the `Date` object will be instantiated once the `reducer.js` is required, and that would be after the `setSystemTime` is invoked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's not working inside `fakeAsync` function. I kept seeing the real date when i console log. Removing the test from `fakeAsync` and I can see the mocked date.